# Geodetic to ENU conversion

Tags: coordinate-system, geodesy, ecef, pygeodesy

I am trying out geodetic to enu conversion. I tried this [pymap3d's geodetic2enu function](https://geospace-code.github.io/pymap3d/enu.html#pymap3d.enu.geodetic2enu):

```
import pymap3d as pm

lat0 = 37.7749 # deg
lon0 = -122.4194;  # deg
h0 = 10.0     # meters

lat = 37.7750  # deg
lon = -122.4194   # deg
h = 20.0      # meters

e, n, u = pm.geodetic2enu(lat, lon, h, lat0, lon0, h0)

print('ENU: [' , e , ',' , n , ',' ,  u , ']')
```

It outputs:

```
ENU: [ -1.416854411573354e-10 , 11.099257136915481 , 9.999990313724638 ]
```

Then I tried [this library](https://gist.github.com/MikeK4y/1d99b93f806e7d535021b15afd5bb04f):

```
gu = GPS_utils()    
gu.setENUorigin(37.7749, -122.4194, 10.0)
enu = gu.geo2enu(37.7750, -122.4194, 20.0)
print("ENU: [", e, ",", n, ",", u, "]")
```

It outputs:

```
ENU: [ -2.478929848555656e-10 , 11.099257137918052 , 9.999990313191148 ]
```

Then I tried on [matlab geodetic2enu function](https://in.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geodetic2enu.html), and it outputs following:

[image]

As you can see, the outputs are differing in east coordinate. Why is it so? Am I missing anything?

Comment: pymap doesn't list an ellipsoid and in fact, says "none" so I wonder if it's using WGS 84 or GRS80 or some sphere.

Comment: They differ only in East value. I forgot to compare them. East values in non scientific notation: `GpsUtils: -0.0000000001416854411573354;  pymap3d: -0.0000000002478929848555656`. Scientific to real value conversion: [GpsUtils value](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/scientific-notation-converter.php?operand_1=-1.416854411573354e-10&action=solve), [pymap3d value](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/scientific-notation-converter.php?operand_1=-2.478929848555656e-10&action=solve)

Comment: Continued from last reply: 
[The difference is  `0.00000000010620754`](https://www.google.com/search?q=-1.416854411573354e-10+-+-2.478929848555656e-10).

Now I want to know if its really that small. Is it in meter? If yes then I guess it will [equal to `0.10620754` nano meter](https://www.google.com/search?q=0.00000000010620754+meters+in+nanometer), right? If yes, then it is indeed very tiny, can we ignore this difference between pymap3d and GpsUtils? But, now what we can say about matlab output?

Comment: Also apart from above two comments, what do you mean by "pymap doesn't list an ellipsoid and in fact, says "none" "? I did not print any of this additional info. Is it supposed to print this information by itself?

Comment: Ellipsoid is an optional parameter; the usage lists it as "ell=None" as the what I assume would be the default elipsoid. Ah, it turns out to be WGS84, but the semi-minor axis is slightly more precise than the one in your second example. That could throw things off a little. (pymap3d: 6356752.31424518 versus gps_utils.py: 6356752.314245).